# Query running very slow with more joins added (live server only)

Tags: mysql, join, explain

I'm having an issue with a large query, with a lot of joins.

To try and explain it simply, there is not a set number of joins the query will do, that depends on the item the report is being run against and various other conditions.

I can't paste the query in here as it goes over the character limit, so here's a screenshot of what I'm running at the moment:

[image]

The issue is that, one of these reports is running incredibly slowly on one of the live servers.

I've tested the above query on my local machine and it's running fine, and doing an **EXPLAIN** shows that each JOIN is using type "ref" with auto keys, and it returns in under a second.

[image]

However, on the live machine it's taking so long that it sends the CPU usage up to 100% and has to be restarted. I've experimented with taking out the joins one by one, and noticed that once you hit a certain point, the time it takes grows exponentially, for example the query might take 3-5 seconds, then adding another join takes it to about 10, then another to about 30, then another to about 60, until it just ends up crashing everything.

I ran an **EXPLAIN** on the query on the live machine and I noticed something different. If you have up to 5 JOINS, then they all use the type "ref" and everything is fine, but as soon as you go up to 6 joins or more, the 6th and above use the type "ALL". It makes no difference which join is the 6th, or which order you put them in.

[image]

I'm guessing that that is the problem, as, as more joins are added back into the query, they are all doing the join on "ALL", although I could be wrong.

I've tested other much simpler queries, and adding more than 6 joins doesn't cause this problem there, so it seems to just be this query, but only on the live machine... Local and live have the same keys and indexes.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? As i'm quite confused.

Let me know if you need extra information.

**Edit:** Just to mention I have copied the database from live and am running it exactly as it is on live, on my local, and it's working fine...

Cheers.

Comment: Setting optimizer_switch=block_nested_loop=off seems to have resolved the issue, though I don't know if it's the right solution or not.